# How to play this file?

Tags: video, plugins, video-player, totem, mkv

[image: Properties of the file]

I have this video file with the extension .mkv but it is not playing in totem video player and this works in the new versions of VLC(Windows) and I havent tried it on VLC for Ubuntu yet. Is there any way to make this file run on the default totem player?

Comment: Why don't you just install vlc for Ubuntu? That should work - especially if you already know if works on VLC under windows. `sudo apt-get install vlc`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. This answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/426113/497359) solved the problem.

I followed the last one , i.e,

Install vlc with `sudo apt-get install vlc`
and then install the required plugins to play *.mkv files by `sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265`

Note that, if the plugin installation gave you an error of not found, you will need to add it to the repo first

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265
sudo apt-get update
```

Now try opening the file in vlc.

Comment: Was driving myself crazy with various attempts until I found this solution.  "sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265" works great, after first adding the repository!  THANK YOU for posting this solution!

Comment: `Ubuntu 14.04 > Ubuntu software center > Search for VLC > Install` directly worked for me. Without additional codecs. Holy ubuntu and holy stackoverflow =)

Comment: exactly @voghDev

Comment: i still get 'unable to locate package' i am using 18.04

Comment: @voghDev - Can you make that an Answer? I tried the `sudo apt-get install vlc`, only to be met with "no apt package 'vlc', but there is a snap with that name."  But thanks to your comment, I got it :D

Comment: Hi @BruceWayne, you're welcome :) I meant searching in the ubuntu software center GUI, not the apt console command. Was this what you tried?

Comment: @voghDev yeah, sorry if my comment wasn't clear. I found it via the GUI following the steps you gave. :)

Comment: Ok cool! Gonna add an answer also, so people can find it easier :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

I found it using the Ubuntu Software Center GUI instead of calling `apt` via console.

`Ubuntu 14.04 > Ubuntu software center > Search for "VLC" > Install`

This is whaty worked for me. No additional codecs needed.

Hope it works for you too!

Answer (score 1):

I tried implementing solution given by @severus, but still I got the error. I solved the probelm by installing an additional package using this command.

`sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-libde265`

Answer (score 0):

Please go online (you must have internet connection running) when you try to run that file it will ask to search required codec then say yes it will install required codec, that's it.

Otherwise try this one:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: I had an active internet connection when I tried to run the file and it said **Required plugin could not be found**, and I've installed 'ubuntu-restricted-extras' and other video codecs play without any problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the ffmpeg plugin for GStreamer. Install it with the following command.

sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-libav