# VLC 2.2.1 doesn't play HEVC/H.265 encoded videos

Tags: 14.04, vlc, hevc

When I try to play H.265 encoded videos on VLC Player 2.2.1 (WeatherMax) on Ubuntu 14.04, I get the following error:

```
Codec not supported:
VLC could not decode the format "hevc" (MPEG-H Part2/HEVC (H.265))
```

I can play the same videos using other tools like the standard `Videos` player on Ubuntu and `MP4Client` from GPAC. Is there any additional libraries or plugin to install for VLC to play H.265 videos?

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```

source: [How to install H.265 / HEVC codec on Ubuntu Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362745/how-to-install-h-265-hevc-codec-on-ubuntu-linux)

Answer (score 2):

VLC is often way behind on format support, because they don't update their copy of ffmpeg very often.  [mpv](http://mpv.io/) is the mplayer / mplayer2 fork that I prefer for playing video.  (Or see @Hassan's answer).

Also note that it's [Weather**wax**](http://discworld.wikia.com/wiki/Esmerelda_Weatherwax), not max.   On the plus side, that means there's some really excellent comic fantasy fiction you can probably have the pleasure of reading for the first time :)

Answer (score 1):

vlc says clearly it has no way to support hevc, and i you already has some alternatives. But what i recommend as the best alternative is Kodi media centre (http://kodi.tv/). Its opensource, of course its free, and its not just a player, its a media center. It runs amazing on linux systems.