# Raspberry Pi 5- Ubuntu 23.10 - H.265 codec Video not playing smoothly- H.265 / HEVC

Tags: vlc, raspberrypi, 23.10, hevc

I'm trying to play H.265 codec video file(which can be 4k,1080 or even lesser resolution file) in default as well as VLC, it shows only first frame and then never resume playback from there.

I tried to follow below links:

- [How to install H.265 / HEVC codec on Ubuntu Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362745/how-to-install-h-265-hevc-codec-on-ubuntu-linux)
- [VLC 2.2.1 doesn't play HEVC/H.265 encoded videos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655457/vlc-2-2-1-doesnt-play-hevc-h-265-encoded-videos)

But terminal throws below error:

```
Err:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu mantic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::81 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

**Note:**
Same 4k video plays fine in raspiOS(x64) using VLC(default setting). So it's something to do with ubuntu OS.

Kindly provide your input.