# Can't play HD .mkv files (even in vlc)

Tags: codecs

I am not able to play any HD **.mkv** files in vlc. (No problems with low quality videos). Here for example,

[image]

It says "**Unfortunately there is no way to fix this**", **really???**

when the same video is played in **Videos**, I get this:

[image]

**And.... this:**

[image]

Some times I get a little bit different error messages (for a different video)

That goes like this:

[image]

**Note:**

1. In the first video, I can hear the audio.
2. I need to play these videos no matter which player. (**Any video player** )
3. Yes, I have Installed "**Ubuntu restricted extras**" with all optional add-ons.

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

After following this: [How to install H.265 / HEVC codec on Ubuntu Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362745/how-to-install-h-265-hevc-codec-on-ubuntu-linux) have installed `vlc-plugin-libde265` and `gstreamer0.10-libde265 gstreamer1.0-libde265`.

Even after doing this, the second error (VP90,undf) still exists . But the first video is playing in a very bad way (green everywhere ) **I have recorded it and it is** [**here**](https://youtu.be/NEZ7aZSIA5U) (Audio is not recorded but i can hear it)

Link to download one of the video which can't be played on mine is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3mN95k6QkkIcXJhYV9ZOXBNcWc/view?usp=sharing) checkout if it plays on your PC.

Output of `apt-cache policy gstreamer0.10-libde265 gstreamer1.0-libde265 vlc-plugin-libde265 ubuntu-restricted-extras` :

```
    vishwa@vishwa-PC:~$ apt-cache policy gstreamer0.10-libde265 gstreamer1.0-libde265 vlc-plugin-libde265 ubuntu-restricted-extras
gstreamer0.10-libde265:
  Installed: 0.1.12-1ppa1~trusty1
  Candidate: 0.1.12-1ppa1~trusty1
  Version table:
 *** 0.1.12-1ppa1~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
gstreamer1.0-libde265:
  Installed: 0.1.12-1ppa1~trusty1
  Candidate: 0.1.12-1ppa1~trusty1
  Version table:
 *** 0.1.12-1ppa1~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
vlc-plugin-libde265:
  Installed: 0.1.7-1ppa1~trusty1
  Candidate: 0.1.7-1ppa1~trusty1
  Version table:
 *** 0.1.7-1ppa1~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
ubuntu-restricted-extras:
  Installed: 60.1
  Candidate: 60.1
  Version table:
 *** 60.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     60 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install H.265 / HEVC codec on Ubuntu Linux?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/362745/how-to-install-h-265-hevc-codec-on-ubuntu-linux)

Comment: @CharlesGreen , will it fix  VP90 and undf errors too? (last image)

Comment: I doubt it - it should fix the H.265 / HEVC error.  I would be tempted to tell you to do a search on "VP90 VLC Ubuntu"

Comment: @CharlesGreen I doubt its still duplicate of [ How to install H.265 / HEVC codec on Ubuntu Linux?] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/362745/how-to-install-h-265-hevc-codec-on-ubuntu-linux)

Comment: @markkirby Yes, I have installed Ubuntu-restricted-extras with all optional add-ons

Comment: Please [edit] and add output of `apt-cache policy gstreamer0.10-libde265 gstreamer1.0-libde265  vlc-plugin-libde265 ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Answer (score 5):

HEVC and VP9 decoders are missing on your system. To install VLC HEVC plugin try:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```

You could also try out [MP4Client Player from GPAC](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/).

**Edit:** GPAC will for sure play HEVC content but I'm not sure if it also supports VP9. Please ensure to install Latest available binaries from the GPAC site and avoid using `apt-get install gpac` in this case.

Comment: I tried your solution. but errors still exist (please see the question EDIT section)

Comment: VP9 error still exists because this command only installs HEVC (H.265) VLC plugin. Did you also try out GPAC, I have good experience with it.

Comment: Is that a video player??

Comment: Not only. If you install the package you will get bunch of video tools. The player is called Osmo4 or MP4Client.

Comment: please visit https://youtu.be/NEZ7aZSIA5U  once , you will get a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: I saw it. This green video artefacts maybe caused by obsolete implementation of `vlc-plugin-libde265`. I still suggest you to try out GPAC. Just go to the `Downloads -> Nightly builds` and select latest available debian package.

Comment: @VishwaPrakashHV I tried to decode your .mkv file that you uploaded. And GPAC can play it without any artefacts. Of course I was not able to decode it with a high frame rate. 4K is to much for my notebook )))

Comment: please join me in a chatroom. need to talk to you more

Comment: @VishwaPrakashHV regarding the problem with missing `.gpacrc` I simulated the same procedure like you did yesterday. (installing it first with  `apt-get install gpac`) and I had the same problem but after downloading [debian package](http://download.tsi.telecom-paristech.fr/gpac/latest_builds/linux64/gpac/gpac_0.5.2-DEV-latest-master_amd64.deb) and installing it (just double click it) this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-libde265

sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libde265

sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```

Comment: OP claims that they already performed the first 4 steps and the top answer recommends the last step and provides more information about it. Please don't repeat duplicate existing answers (badly)!