# Is there a HEVC decoder for Ubuntu 14.04, without the need to install external PPA?

Tags: 14.04, video, vlc, hevc

I recently got a few video files that are in HEVC format.

VLC plays just the audio after displaying message that it can't decode HEVC format, and that "there was nothing 'I' could do about it!"

My Ubuntu is 14.04 latest. VLC is 2.1.6.

I am paranoid (about installing random stuff on my PC) and will not install any unofficial or unknown PPA.

Is there any way I can play these HEVC files without having to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 (I believe the VLC in Ubuntu 15.10 has HEVC decoding)? Is it possible to force-install latest VLC on Ubuntu 14.04? I want to stick with 14.04 until its EOL, as this is my production system.

Please do not point me to "possible duplicates" as I DO NOT want to install or refer to any public repository (PPA) that is not vetted (or packaged) by Canonical (or authorized contributors, if any). Hence, this is a different question.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install H.265 / HEVC codec on Ubuntu Linux?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/362745/how-to-install-h-265-hevc-codec-on-ubuntu-linux)

Comment: No friend, my question is different. I edited it to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

14.04 does not provide a HEVC codec. There is simply no way to do this in a manner that is vetted by Canonical.

You have to either:

- [Add a repo that provides one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362745/how-to-install-h-265-hevc-codec-on-ubuntu-linux)
- Grab the code from upstream, "vet it" yourself and build it.

Even if you cherry pick the packages from 16.04, it's the Debian Multimedia Maintainers and Ubuntu MOTUs, not Canonical who are looking after the package.