# how can I install 5kplayer in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hevc

I downloaded a video with `MKV` format. but when i try to run it some error pops up then i realize encoding of this video is not supported for my media players. the format is `HEVC x265`. I search a lot and finally land a media player called `5kplayer`. I check the official website of the player it supported windows and mac. but i can't find support for linux or ubuntu.
Is there any way to install 5kplayer in ubuntu 14.04.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install H.265 / HEVC codec on Ubuntu Linux?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/362745/how-to-install-h-265-hevc-codec-on-ubuntu-linux)

Answer (score 0):

There is  no official support for 5Kplayer in linux but you could use wine to install it in ubuntu.If u just want to play HEVC files you can use vlc which is natively supported in ubuntu.To install vlc

```
sudo apt-get install vlc && sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```