# Unable to locate package vlc-plugin-libde265

Tags: software-installation, vlc, video-player

For playing the videos with `.mkv` extension, I installed `vlc player` in ubuntu 14.04.

Now, while installing the vlc plugins, it is giving the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc-plugin-libde265
```

Comment: What did you type to install the VLC plugins?

Comment: sudo apt-get install  vlc-plugin-libde265

Comment: I think you need to install it using the PPA at https://launchpad.net/~strukturag/+archive/ubuntu/libde265.

Comment: This answer might help you : http://askubuntu.com/a/426113/497359

Comment: @SeverusTux Ah, good find. This question is a duplicate then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vlc-plugin-libde265` is not available in the Ubuntu repositories as can be seen at http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=vlc-plugin-libde265. To install it, you have to add the PPA at https://launchpad.net/~strukturag/+archive/ubuntu/libde265:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```

Comment: Hi. I have added this ppa, and it still says unable to locate package vlc-plugin-libde265. I have enabled all Ubuntu sources.

Comment: @ПротивГлобал What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: It is 17.04 64-bit.

Comment: @ПротивГлобал Yeah the PPA wouldn't work for 17.04. You need to find something else.

Comment: OK, I will try to find solution.

Comment: Did you find another solution